# Is there a limit of how many down votes a question can get

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

Is there a limit of how many down votes a question can get? I was thinking that there might be if the value of votes is stored as a short or int and that you can max out at those many down votes. Now my question is is my thinking flawed or is it right and if it is not please explain to me.

Edit this is not about if it would get removed or not
Note I'm not counting the fact that if it got over 30 down voted it would probably be deleted.

Comment: but why? is it because there is a big data type in the code

Comment: If you mean from a coding perspective then there would be a variable to hold the amount of votes right and if it was declared as an int or short...ect then it would have a limit. Now i do know this is a hypothetical question.

Comment: So is there an unlimited data type for the variable that stores the down votes

Comment: @ ben is (neb :-) ) backwards  My question is not asking if it will be closed or not I'm just wondering if there is a limit to the amount because of the way the website is coded

Comment: Yes, it's the least of `2*(2^32 - 1)` and the number of non-suspended users with 125 reputation or more, as described in the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no limit except that you need 125 rep to downvote and you can only downvote once so that makes the limit equal to the number of people on a site with 125 rep excluding the poster of the question/answer.

Posts [can get more than 30 downvotes without being deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly).